# Accessing a file containing key value from list of dictionaries and passing them as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in a .txt file. I am trying to read the file and access values from the file using the keys.

**config.txt**

```
my_list=[{"name1":"abc", "age1":"25", {"name2":"def", "age2":"27"}]
```

**read_config.py**

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    for d in content:
        if 'name1' in d:
            print(d['name1'])
```

No value get returned. Please advise what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the file, `content` is a string that you get, not an actual list, like this:

```
my_list=[{"name1":"abc", "age1":"25"}, {"name2":"def", "age2":"27"}]
```

Hence your loop returns nothing.

Instead, do this:

```
In [948]: import ast
In [960]: with open('config.txt', 'r') as content_file: 
     ...:     content = content_file.read() 
     ...:     splitted_str = content.split('=')[1] 
     ...:     splitted_list = ast.literal_eval(splitted_str) ## to convert string to list 
     ...:     for d in splitted_list: 
     ...:         if 'name1' in d: 
     ...:             print(d['name1']) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading the data from the file with `.read()` it actually returns a string. You therefore iterate over the string, namely each of the characters in it.
To fix it, I would suggest either switching the config.txt file with config.py and instead define the dictionary in plain python. In read_config.py, you could then write the following at the top:

```
from config import my_list
```

This will make the variable `my_list` available within your script so you can use it as you did with `content`.
Also it seems like you're missing a '}' after "age1":25.